# Is there a way to design this code as loops?

Tags: c

I am writing a blurring function, by taking the average of the rgb values of up to 9 pixels (8 pixels plus [i][j]). The if statements ensure that the program does not try to add the pixel to the average if it goes outside the bounds of the 2-D array. The code looks like it's kind of repeating, but then the if statements are not really repeating? Like I could loop inside a loop to make the height go from i - 1 to i + 1, and width from j - 1 to j + 1, but depending on which pixel is being added a different if statement is required. Is there a way to design this better? Thank you.

```
int red = copy[i][j].rgbtRed; //input pixel itself into average. array format copy[height][width].rgbtRed
int n = 1;

if (i != 0 && j != 0)   //input upper left pixel into average
{
    red += copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
    n++;
}
if (i != 0) //pixel directly above
{
    red += copy[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
    n++;
}
if (i != 0 && j != width - 1) // pixel to top right
{
    red += copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
    n++;
}
if (j != 0) // pixel to left
{
    red += copy[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
    n++;
}

// and so on and so forth for all the remaining pixels surrounding [i][j]

float redf = (float) red / (float) n; //take average
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Assume you have `width` and `height` to be the size, you can use `if` and `continue` to skip those pixels that are out of boundary:

```
int red = 0; //input pixel itself into average. array format copy[height][width].rgbtRed
int n = 0;

for (int x=i-1; x<=i+1; ++x) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= height) {
        continue;
    };
    for (int y=j-1; y<=j+1; ++y) {
        if (y < 0 || y >= width) {
            continue;
        }
        red += copy[x][y].rgbtRed;
        n++;
    };
};
float redf = (float) red / (float) n; //take average
```

Comment: Thank you @adrtam!